# How to Give the link to button that contains to specific circle

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, html5-canvas

I am facing the problem in link the specific circle to the button to any specific id circle.

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcLXe.png)

I tried this code.

```
 function redirect()
 { 
    circlePacking({
    containerId: "chartContainer",
    dataURL: "json/all.json",
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    topicId: 1241,
    position:"absolute",
    margin:"50%"
  });
   }

   <button onclick='redirect()'> 
     Click to go to specific id
   </button>


  <script>
  circlePacking({
    containerId: "chartContainer",
    dataURL: "json/all.json",
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    topicId: 11191,
    position:"absolute",
    margin:"50%"
  });
</script>
```

Like I have a lot of circle around the main circle. When i click to anyone then it must go to that circle according to label or given address

Answer (score 0):

Try using case in javascript. Here is the code. I used it for clicking on color pallete. When I click on certaim color it selects it as color. I have modified for you. Hope this will help.

```
      <div  id="maincircle" onclick="selectCircle(this)"></div>

<script>
function selectCircle(obj) {

switch (obj.id) {

case "first":

x = "first";
//Do anything with x like putting it in inner.html or calling link with it

break;

case "second":


x = "second";
//Do anything with x like putting it in inner.html or calling link with it
break;

case "third":

x = "third";
//Do anything with x like putting it in inner.html or calling link with it
break;

</script>
```

Dont forget to give specific id to each circle.

Comment: Is this really going to work with d3.js? I don't think this will work.

Comment: its javascript code.. it will work with every language if you are building an website with html and css

Comment: https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-zoomable-circle-packing       Check this link here is the sample on which I am working. I want to link one circle link with these unique circle or specific circle means If i click circle then it zoom the specific circle that is in the main big circle.